# How to fetch the Jenkins workspace(Linux) from another linux box.

Tags: bash, shell, unix, jenkins

I just used the below command to trigger the job from different linux box. And Its triggered with default parameters

```
curl -d “token=d9c76b6636dfasdf23211135a” -i -X POST https://ciapi-us-central1.gcp.dev.amazon.com/CI-RUN-9571/view/Kindle/job/CI-Run-USA/buildWithParameters/ -k
```

But I just want to download the ${Worksapce} and do some modification with existing workspace files and replace it to original location.

How can I achieve this ? any leads....

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? Maybe there is a different way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot as such share the workspace. But I see other possible options:

1. You could pass a file as a build parameter (possibly an archive of the workspace). Wait for the job execution (via Jenkins REST API). Then archive the result on the linux box. Download the result from the original job.
2. You could use any shared storage so that both boxes share the same file

But ideally things would be simpler if the job triggered could determine by itself the files it needs and publish the result of its work once done.

Comment: I just want to perform it in POST BUILD activity? can you give me some example ti achieve this?

Comment: Which option can you achieve? Do you have a shared service where you could store some files? Like an S3, Artifactory, Nexus, NAS, FTP etc ... ? That would proably be the "best" option